# Google Chat API spaces.setup method. Error 403: "The Chat app developer deactivated this app"

Tags: google-chat

During developer preview phase, the "spaces.setup" method was working fine: we were able to send direct messages between our Chat App and users.

Since "spaces.setup" method has been released to GA, all requests return the following error message:

```js
POST https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces:setup
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The Chat app developer deactivated this app",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The Chat app developer deactivated this app",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I already checked all configs in cloud console to make sure app is enabled.

The new method "spaces.findDirectMessage", on the other hand, works as expected. Also, everything is fine when I add the Chat App to a space and create a message. So, I suspect there's a bug on the "setup" method.

Code of our client in Java:

```java
HangoutsChat service = new HangoutsChat
  .Builder(
     GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), 
     GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
     getServiceAccountCredentials("{{Dest User Email}}", HangoutsChatScopes.CHAT_SPACES))
  .setApplicationName("{{App Name}}").build();
SetUpSpaceRequest setUpSpaceRequest = new SetUpSpaceRequest();
Space space = new Space();
space.setSpaceType("DIRECT_MESSAGE");
space.setSingleUserBotDm(true);
setUpSpaceRequest.setSpace(space);
return service.spaces().setup(setUpSpaceRequest).execute();
```

Expected result: return of a new direct message (Space object) from chat app to user.

Actual behaviour: error 403 described above - "The Chat app developer deactivated this app".